# Unable to move to another page after login using firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase to sign in a user with Google and then redirecting them to user dashboard page. However, once I have logged in, I'm unable to go to any other page on my website. It redirects me to dashboard. How do I fix this?

Here is the code where I'm signing in a user.

```
const [loading,setLoading] = useState(true);
const [user,setUser] = useState(null);
const history = useHistory();

useEffect(()=>{
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user)=>{
        setUser(user);
        setLoading(false);
        if(user)
            history.push("/dashboard");
    })
},[user,history]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user)=>{
  if (user) history.push("/dashboard");
})
```

This line says, "If a user is logged in, redirect them to /dashboard".

Ideally you would have that logic on login/signup page only as the user is already authenticated they should be on the dashboard or any other page.

On other pages where you require the user to be logged in, the logic should be like this:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user)=>{
  if (!user) history.push("/login");
      ^
})
```

This basically says if a user is NOT logged in, redirect them to login but if they are, keep them on the page they are on. For example if you redirect user to `/settings` and if they are logged in, they will stay there.

Comment: OP's code is also retriggering itself and the `onAuthStateChanged` listener isn't being cleaned up properly.

Comment: @samthecodingman it sounds like OP has the same `onAuthStateChanged` on other different components i.e. redirecting to 'dashboard' on any other component.